# Adding Active Directory group with spaces in name gives error in PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have following command to add AD group in PowerShell script but AD group has space in name and that is causing an issue.

```
Set-Variable -Name APP_GROUP -Value My AD Group
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "MyDomain\"$APP_GROUP
```

> Error: CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: RemoteException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Answer (score 3):

Quote it in single quotes, because it's a plain string with nothing else happening, and put the double quotes around the whole thing in the second line (double-quotes because it has a variable name in it which PowerShell needs to expand):

```
Set-Variable -Name APP_GROUP -Value 'My AD Group'
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "MyDomain\$APP_GROUP"
```

It would be more typical to see it written:

```
$APP_GROUP = 'My AD Group'
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "MyDomain\$APP_GROUP"
```

Comment: I can put SD group in quote because its coming from other script and I can not change that script

Comment: @DharmendraSingh: if the name (with embedded spaces) stored in `$APP_GROUP` comes from another script, you don't need to quote _it_ again, but if want to make the value part of a _single argument_ to pass to `Add-LocalGroupMember`, you must make `$APP_GROUP` _part of the double-quoted string_, as this answer shows. Alternatively, omit double quotes altogether (which works in this case, but may not always): `MyDomain\$APP_GROUP`.  Also note that there is no obvious connection between your command and your error message, given that `Add-LocalGroupMember` is not a _native_ command.

Comment: @DharmendraSingh I don't understand; the code in your question shows you tying the group name in; how do you get the group name out of the other script?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I have one aws user data script which will create windows Ec2 instance and this script is part of user data and we are getting ad group name from variable teraform. example I have assigned ad group value in  variable.sh file 
readonly APP_GROUP="My AD Group" and I get this value in UserData script like Set-Variable -Name APP_GROUP -Value My AD Group

Comment: I have not used teraform; that still is not clear to me, how does the text *My AD Group* get into the line `Set-Variable -Name APP_GROUP -Value My AD Group` in your script? Is teraform using your script as a template, and replacing part of it? If so, can you put quotes around where the value will appear like `Set-Variable -Name APP_GROUP -Value 'TERAFORM_THING_HERE'` ?